# Android Marshmallow: How to disable vibrate on call connect?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I recently bought a moto e3 power phone with Android Marshmallow OS. The phone vibrates every time when the receiver takes the call. It is annoying. How to disable this option? I have checked the settings. There is a option "Vibrate for calls". But disabling this option does not remove the vibration.

Comment: This feature is common for Motorola phones, search for Vibrate on Call Connection. I use Samsung, there is no such option.

Comment: @esQmo I use moto e3 power and it also does not have that option :(

Answer (score 1):

Open the dialer and click the 3 dot menu in the upper right corner and select Settings, then Sounds and vibration, under "In-call vibration" there are options for Vibrate on Answer, Vibrate on Call Waiting, and Vibrate on Hang up, select or unselect as desired.

Comment: I use moto e3 power and i tried to do as per suggestion. There are no Vibrate on Answer, Vibrate on Call Waiting, and Vibrate on Hang up options.

Comment: @prashanth I haven't seen the E3 yet, just assumed it was like other AOSP based devices by Moto. Settings - Sound & Notifications would be the only other are it could be, but if this setting is changeable, it should be in the dialer (Phone) apps settings or else it can't be altered.

Comment: Not have this options in moto e3 power.....
Plz help me...

Comment: @Archana Then you may not have the option to change this setting.